# SQL Server Check Constraint Lock Order

Tags: sql-server, locking, deadlock, check-constraints

I'm having problems with SQL Server 2012 filetable.

Filetable defines an check constraint on a `path_locator` field with definition as: `/*ParentsAreDirectories*/ (filetable_parents_are_directories((1381579960),CONVERT([varbinary](892),[path_locator],0),[is_directory])=(1))`. It seems that this check constraint calls some stored procedure or function, definition of which I was unable to found.

Then, sometimes I'm getting a deadlock on simultaneous `INSERT` query into filetable. I think, that deadlock is happens because check constraints of both transactions installs an `S` lock to filetable and then both transactions tries to install 'X' lock to insert a new row.

Basically my question is: In which order SQL Server installs locks caused by check constraints: before main query locks, or after?

And additional question - how to force installation of `X` lock in my scenario with filetable from very begin of transaction, if my interpretation of deadlock cause is correct?

UPD: deadlock report: https://gist.github.com/Snork2/9a4788dad1bc62736ae8